# Cant add an image to leftView of UITextField ios7

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface, ios7, uitextfield

I have a UITextFiled added to a view in Xcode 5.1, I am trying to add image to its left view using code below however when I run all I don't see the image , don't understand the reason , please help

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Key.png"];

[txtCode setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[txtCode setLeftView:imgView];
```

Comment: Did you try with setting a frame for imageview?

Comment: Does `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Key.png"]` return an object? Or does it return nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Frame for the Image View:

```
yourTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Key.png"];

[yourTextField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[yourTextField setLeftView:imgView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you...Add image in paddingView if you want.

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
self.textFiled.leftView = paddingView;
self.textFiled.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```